# Is it possible to express the density of Beta distribution with its mode?

Tags: distributions, beta-distribution

the density of beta distribution can be express in term of mean and variance as

$$ f(x;\mu,\phi) = \frac{\Gamma(\phi)}{\Gamma{(\mu\phi)}\Gamma((1-\mu)\phi)}x^{\mu\phi-1}(1-x)^{(1-\mu)\phi - 1}$$

where $\mu$ is the mean and $\phi$ is the inverse of variance.

Now I'm wondering if its possible express the density of beta in term of its mode (along with other parameters)? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the general case, no.  Consider the special case of a Beta distribution with (standard) parameters $a \leq 1, b > 1$.  The mode is $0$, and it should be clear that if you know the mode is $0$ you will still need at least two other parameters to be able to fix $a$ and $b$ - which would render the mode useless, because if you are going to specify two other parameters, you can just specify $a$ and $b$ (or the mean and variance, as you have done) and do without the mode altogether.

If you allow only Beta distributions with a central mode, equivalent to restricting $a > 1, b > 1$, then the answer is yes.  The mode in this case is:

$$m = {a-1 \over a+b-2}$$

and so the mode and either of $a$ or $b$ is sufficient to deduce the other parameter.  In fact, the mode and the mean together are sufficient, as there is a 1-1 map from $(a,b)$ to $(\text{mode}, \text{mean})$ - unless $a = b$, in which case the mode $=$ the mean $= 0.5$, and $a$ and $b$ can be any numbers as long as they are equal.

Comment: Hi; Thanks for the reply; yea; because I'm doing beta regression in which case my response variable can take extreme value (0,1) it indicates that I can't model my output as beta distribution with mean 0, or 1. That's why I'm thinking of using response as my mode instead. May you have a better idea ? (may be this leads to a different post discussion I guess then.)

Comment: What *is* your response variable?

Comment: hi the response variable gonna take value in $[0,1]$

Comment: Yes, but what is it in the real world?

Comment: It will be a parameter of Bernoulli; so its a probability of being 0 or 1